# Trying to move users between voice channels using discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

**For anybody having the same problem, you can check below for all the comments but here is a TD;DR:** First, I got the channel I wanted and saved it into a variable, then I got the author of the message and finally I used the move_to code.

`async def moveplayer(ctx): channel = bot.get_channel(738705076557709392) member = ctx.message.author await member.move_to(channel)`

I really enjoy doing coding, but I'm not the best at it. Recently, I've been trying to get better at using python for things that will actually help me, rather than fun text-based games. What I'm trying to do now is I want the bot to move a user from one voice channel to another when a specific command is used. I've been trying to find solutions all over stackoverflow and the rest of the internet, but everything I've come across hasn't worked for me. Below are some things that I've already tried. I've also tried using `client = discord.Client()` rather than `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='hp!')`, but nothing seems to work.

```
@bot.command(name='moveme')
@commands.has_role('HpBotAccess')
async def moveplayer(*ctx,**message):
    voiceChannel = bot.get_channel(738704912912744450)
    await client.move_to(message.author, voiceChannel.id)
```

```
@bot.command(name='moveme')
@commands.has_role('HpBotAccess')
async def moveplayer(message):
    channel = discord.utils.find(lambda x: x.name == 'Vibin 3', message.server.channels)
    await client.move_member(message.author, channel)
```

```
@bot.command(name='moveme')
@commands.has_role('HpBotAccess')
async def moveplayer(message):
    await move_to(716193638433947690)
```

I've also tried reading the docs but I don't really understand them, and so the above is just what I've tried experimenting with from other posts/a little bit of the docs. If you do have a solution or can help me please post it! Thank you!

P.S. I realise this question has already been posted before however the solutions on other posts didn't work for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a function that does something similar on my discord.py bot. I think your problem is that you need to call `member.move_to(channel)`. For example, my bot does the following

```
channel = client.get_channel({channel ID here}) 
# channel now holds the channel you want to move people into

member = client.get_member({user_id of person to move})
#member now holds the user that you want to move

await member.move_to(channel)
```

You need to use `move_to` on a `member` Class, and it takes as a parameter a `channel`. You need to use the `client` to extract the relevant data to operate on.

Comment: I've tried adding in what you said but I keep getting given the 'TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'' problem. The code I have so far is 

`@bot.command(name='runintowall')
@commands.has_role('HpBotAccess')
async def moveplayer(member):
 channel = client.get_channel(738705076557709392)
 member = client.get_member(325914133356609537)
 await member.move_to(channel)`

Comment: So that error is saying that the function `moveplayer` isn't being passed the `member` argument, try passing `ctx`; something like `async def moveplayer(ctx)`

Comment: The issue then is that I get an error saying that its missing one potential argument - 'member'...

`TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'`

Comment: Hmm. Are you using `client = discord.Client()` or `bot = commands.bot()`? If you're using client, try using bot instead, with `async def moveplayer(ctx)`, and replace all `client` in my answer code with `bot`

Comment: I was using bot = commands.bot() but didn't change all the client parts around. After changing them, nothing happens except I get the error `TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'` again. This is my current code:
`@bot.command(name='runintowall')
@commands.has_role('HpBotAccess')
async def moveplayer(ctx):
 channel = bot.get_channel(738705076557709392)
 member = bot.get_member(325914133356609537)
 await member.move_to(channel)`
After this I will be gone for a bit so I wont be able to answer for a bit. If I don't talk to you till later, ty for ur help.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure then. I have a hunch the problem might be somewhere else in your code, but I can't be certain.

Comment: alright, I'll respond to my answer with the entire code if it helps :)

Comment: The error for that problem was apparently in another piece of code that checked for messages, and so it would check for the message before anything else and then screw up the rest of the code! I'll see if your fixes work now!
EDIT: Have just given it a shot and its giving me the error:
`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_member'`

Comment: It's all fixed up now, I just had to get rid of get_member and instead I used `ctx.message.author` which gave me the correct result! Thank you so much for helping me work through this problem and for your push in the right direction!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, even if it was a bit of a roundabout process to getting your code working