# How to create "Join To Create Room " in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to Discord.py, I am facing problem when after `setup` command create a category and create voice channel named `Create room` inside, when user click on voice channel created by `setup` , will immediately create another channel and move members inside it

setup command:

```
@bot.command()
async def setup(ctx):
    try:
        guild = bot.get_guild(id) 
        await ctx.send("Success !")
        new_category = await ctx.guild.create_category_channel("Voice Chat")
        new_channel = await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel("Create Room", category=new_category)
    except Exception as errors:
        print(f"Bot Error: {errors}")
```

Now I want when user join `Create Room`, they will be moved to a new channel and when everyone exits will delete the channel, thanks! (btw sorry for my english)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to move users between voice channels using discord.py bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63200706/trying-to-move-users-between-voice-channels-using-discord-py-bot)

Comment: Everytime create a new category it will have a different id, how can I get them except copy the id but still get its id ?